# Python Fabric - How to provide git credentials?

Tags: python, git, fabric

I have been using python fabric for deploying my Django projects. Over the time the deployment has spanned multiple servers. The Fab script downloads code from git on the server and deploys. And it does that for every server.

My git access is through email and password. How can i avoid entering my email & password for each server every time i deploy? Git credentials cache doesn't seem to help.

I would like to avoid using SSH key based authentication for GIT.

Comment: I'm curious as to why you want to avoid ssh keys..

Comment: The GIT repo is not mine. Access has been granted to me using username and password authentication, but not SSH. I can ask for it, but i want to keep that as a last option.

Comment: Huh. ok. Well, it s my understanding you can do this: `git clone https://USERNAME:PASSWORD@github.com/USER/PROJECT.git`

Comment: @G.D.Singh hey, did you find a solution to this? I'm trying to find a solution to the same problem now.

Comment: @OzgurAkcali I created a python fabric task which would ask my GIT credentials whenever i deploy. It configures the GIT repo URL as said by @Javier. 

`https://USERNAME:PASSWORD@github.com/USER/PROJECT.git`


So i need to enter git username and password once everytime i deploy on all servers. 

But i will be moving to SSH access soon.

Comment: @G.D.Singh thanks a lot

Comment: One thing to note, username:password doesn't appear to work if you have special characters in the password e.g. @ - and unfortunately urlencoding the password doesn't help.

Answer (score 2):

For people coming to this question with fabric 2, I have found the following works:

```
from invoke import Responder

git_watchers = [
  Responder(pattern = r"Username for .*", response="git_user\n"), 
  Responder(pattern = r"Password for .*", response="git_password\n") ]

ctxt.run("git fetch", pty=True, watchers=git_watchers)
```

Hope this helps.